# php array search value

Tags: php, arrays, search

```
$arr = "Array
(
    [industry] => Array
        (
            [0] => Automotive_industry
            [1] => Automotive_industry
            [2] => Restaurant
            [3] => Restaurant
            [4] => Restaurant
            [5] => Restaurant
            [6] => Automotive_industry
            [7] => Automotive_industry
            [8] => Restaurant
            [9] => Role-playing_game
            [10] => Bicycle
            [11] => Automotive_industry
            [12] => Automotive_industry
            [13] => Automotive_industry
            [14] => Automotive_industry
            [15] => Restaurant
            [16] => Restaurant
            [17] => Restaurant
            [18] => Restaurant
            [19] => Automotive_industry
            [20] => Automotive_industry
            [21] => Restaurant
            [22] => Role-playing_game
            [23] => Bicycle
            [24] => Automotive_industry
            [25] => Automotive_industry
        )

    [product] => Array
        (
            [0] => Motorcycle
            [1] => Motorcycle
            [2] => French_fries
            [3] => Poutine
            [4] => Sandwich
            [5] => Milkshake
            [6] => Motorcycle
            [7] => Scooter_(motorcycle)
            [8] => Hamburger
            [9] => Champions_(role-playing_game)
            [10] => Bicycle
            [11] => Scooter_(motorcycle)
            [12] => Scooter_(motorcycle)
            [13] => Motorcycle
            [14] => Motorcycle
            [15] => French_fries
            [16] => Poutine
            [17] => Sandwich
            [18] => Milkshake
            [19] => Motorcycle
            [20] => Scooter_(motorcycle)
            [21] => Hamburger
            [22] => Champions_(role-playing_game)
            [23] => Bicycle
            [24] => Scooter_(motorcycle)
            [25] => Scooter_(motorcycle)
        )

    [iri] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_MotoCorp
            [1] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_MotoCorp
            [2] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_Certified_Burgers
            [3] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_Certified_Burgers
            [4] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_Certified_Burgers
            [5] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_Certified_Burgers
            [6] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_MotoCorp
            [7] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_MotoCorp
            [8] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_Certified_Burgers
            [9] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_Games
            [10] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_Cycles
            [11] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_MotoCorp
            [12] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_MotoCorp
            [13] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_MotoCorp
            [14] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_MotoCorp
            [15] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_Certified_Burgers
            [16] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_Certified_Burgers
            [17] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_Certified_Burgers
            [18] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_Certified_Burgers
            [19] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_MotoCorp
            [20] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_MotoCorp
            [21] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_Certified_Burgers
            [22] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_Games
            [23] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_Cycles
            [24] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_MotoCorp
            [25] => http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hero_MotoCorp
        )

)";
```

I want to search the wrod from above array 
Word "Motorcycle" and get the iri http path.

any help ??

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say if you wanted them all or just the first.

```
$val = "Motorcycle";


// only first
$ind = array_search ( $val, $arr ["product"], true );
if ($ind >= 0) {
    echo  $arr ["iri"] [$ind] . "<br>";
}

echo "<hr>" ;

// all values
foreach ( array_keys ( $arr ["product"], $val, true ) as $ind ) {
    echo $arr ["iri"] [$ind] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a look at the `array` you have given and would like to point out a few facts:

- `"Motorcycle"` is inside `"product"`
- `"Motorcycle"` is duplicate, so we need to be able to decide which `"Motorcycle"`'s previous are we searching for
- `"Motorcycle"` appears as a `substring` in a case-insensitive manner at several locations

So, first let us implement a function which will find the corresponding `iri` of a `string`. Note that we need to decide whether we are searching for more `iri` elements if they are duplicate and whether we want it to be case-sensitive:

```
function getIri($input, $str, $duplicates = false, $caseInsensitive = false) {
    $output = array();
    foreach ($input["iri"] as $element) {
        if (($caseInsensitive && (stripos($element, $str) >= 0)) ||
           (strpos($element, $str) >= 0)) {
               $output[]=$element;
               if (!$duplicates) {
                   return $output;
               }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Then, you will need to do the same with `product`:

```
function getPreviousProductOf($input, $str, $duplicates = false, $caseInsensitive = false, $substring = false) {
    $output = array();
    //We start from 1, as the 0'th element does not have a previous
    for ($index = 1; $index < count($input["product"]); $index++) {
        if (($substring && $caseInsensitive && (stripos($input["product"][$index], $str) >= 0)) ||
           ($substring && !$caseInsensitive && (strpos($input["product"][$index], $str) >= 0)) ||
           (!$substring && $caseInsensitive && (strcasecmp($input["product"][$index], $str) === 0)) ||
           (!$substring && !$caseInsensitive && ($input["product"][$index] === $str))) {
            $output = array_merge($output, getIri($input, $input["product"][$index]), $duplicate, $caseInsensitive);
            if (!$duplicate) {
                return $output;
            }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Finally, you need to call the second `function`, like this:

```
var $result = getPreviousProductOf($input, "Motorcycle");
```